# "Well dressed" vs "well-dressed"

Tags: word-order, hyphens, compounds, orthography

In my English exercise book there is this sentence:

> **The young lady is well dressed.**

It asks to rephrase it in a new sentence, and provides this solution:

> **The well dressed young lady.**

I think that the sentence above should be:

> **The well-dressed young lady** (a hyphen between the words well and dressed).
>   Am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, but neither is your book. I would employ the hyphen; but it is not obligatory, it is merely a courtesy to the reader. In this case its omission does not seem to me create any ambiguity.

Comment: The book's suggested rephrasing isn't a complete sentence.

Answer (score 4):

As per StoneyB's comment, the hyphen is effectively *optional*.

In OP's specific example, most people probably *would* include it, but grammatically the usage is no different in, say,...

> [*a **recently published** review*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22uncomfortable%20talk%20about%20narcissism%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a%20recently%20published%20review%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099)

...which as you'll see if you follow the link, most writers *don't* hyphenate.

---

Since language is primarily *spoken*, one must be careful when suggesting the presence or absence of the hyphen has any semantic significance. But sometimes there really is a difference - for example,...

> "It won't work properly unless you do the right mouse click"

...where it's possible the *right (**correct**) mouse-click* is in fact a ***left*** (or ***middle***) click. This is one of those rare cases where (in principle) the written form can be less ambiguous than the spoken form...

> 1: *right-mouse-click* (definitely the one on the opposite side to the *left-mouse-click*).
>    2: *right mouse click* (completely ambiguous)
>    3: *right mouse-click*  (potentially ambiguous)

Some native speakers will think they can unambiguously indicate whether they mean *right=correct* or *right=[opposite of left]* depending on stress patterns and pauses, but in practice many native *listeners* still won't be 100% sure what was meant.